# executing n iterations of for loop in parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Let's assume we have a nested `for` loop in python, where the innermost loop calls some function `fun`:

```
for x1 in ['a','b','c','d','e']:
    for x2 in [1,2,3]:
        fun(x1,x2)
```

How could this be rewritten, such that `n` calls of `fun` are executed in parallel?
I.e. for `n==2`, the order of execution would be:

- `fun('a',1)` and `fun('a',2)` run in parallel.
- when one of them terminates, `fun('a',3)` is started
- when one of them terminates, `fun('b',1)` is started
- ... and so on

How could this be achieved in the most *pythonic* way?

Comment: multiprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    l2 = [1, 2, 3]
    n = 2
    with Pool(n) as pool:
        pool.starmap(fun, product(l1, l2))
```

Using [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) we create all the pairs in a row:

```py
>>> list(product(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]))
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Then, we can create a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) with `n` processes, and pass each pair to `fun` using the [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) function.

By creating the [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) and passing the first parameter `n` we have `n` processes that take each element from the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) by order, so this creates exactly the effect you were looking for - whenever one of them frees up, it will take the next pair in line.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the parameters in a list comprehension. Then you can use `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap` to call a function with multiple arguments.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

x1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
x2 = [1,2,3]

param_combinations = [(i, j) for i in x1 for j in x2] 

def func(x, y):
    return f'{x}_{y}'

with Pool(processes=3) as p:
    results = p.starmap(func, param_combinations)

>>>results
['a_1',
 'a_2',
 'a_3',
 'b_1',
 'b_2',
 'b_3',
 'c_1',
 'c_2',
 'c_3',
 'd_1',
 'd_2',
 'd_3',
 'e_1',
 'e_2',
 'e_3']
```